# How can i use one Route for all subRoutes in react-router-dom v6

Tags: react-router, navigation, react-router-dom

I have route <Route path="login" element={} />, how can I use this route in all routes: /main:page, /main/post:id.
For example, when I visit /main/post:id, I want to see the PostCurrent component and the SignIn component on the same page. I guess I'm explaining my problem correctly.
I'm using v6 of react-router.

```
   <Routes>
    <Route path="/main" element={<Main />}>
      <Route path=":page" element={<><PostList /><Pagination /></>} />
      <Route path="post/:id" element={<PostCurrent />} />
      <Route path="login" element={<SignIn />} />
    </Route>
    <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
        <Route path="post-form" element={<PostForm />} />
        <Route path="post-list" element={<PostListDashBoard />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/main/0" replace />} />
  </Routes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render both the `SignIn` component on both the `"/:page"` and `"/post/:id"` routes then create a layout route to render `SignIn` and an `Outlet` for the nested `Route` components.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const MainLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Outlet />
    <SignIn />
  </>
);
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/main" element={<Main />}>

    // Layout route rendering Signin w/ nested routes
    <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
      <Route
        path=":page"
        element={<><PostList /><Pagination /></>}
      />
      <Route path="post/:id" element={<PostCurrent />} />
    </Route>

    <Route path="login" element={<SignIn />} />
  </Route>

  <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
      <Route path="post-form" element={<PostForm />} />
      <Route path="post-list" element={<PostListDashBoard />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/main/0" replace />} />
</Routes>
```